# C# and hex offset range

Tags: c#, hex

Sorry for a newbie question. I have a game save file which contains some information about game character. I want to change some stats, for example money or skills and I know where is the data but I don't understand how to work with hex range offset. For example, I know that skill points are between 4863-4866 and How will be correct to read and to write new values?

[image]

My attempts in code:

```
        int skill = 0;

        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("Player.chr")))
        {
            br.BaseStream.Position = 0x12FF; // read position
            label1.Text = br.ReadInt32().ToString();
        }

        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("Player.chr")))
        {
            bw.Seek(0x12FF, SeekOrigin.Begin); // go to position
            bw.Write(skill + 10); // plus 10 skill points
        }
```

Comment: what did not work in your code? Always saving 10?

Comment: @Dmitry which offset position can I use and will correct? 4863, 4864, 4865, 4866 or all of them?
Меня смущает диапазон offset, типа от и до, я могу в любое из них записывать?

Comment: можно записать только 4 байта, начиная с позиции 4863, а это int32. Если записать побольше, то файл будет битым. 
bw.Seek(0x12FF, SeekOrigin.Begin); bw.Write(100); // значение вместо 100 можно любое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increase value of skill, try correctly read in a variable "skill":

```
        int skill = 0;

        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("Player.chr")))
        {
            bw.Seek(0x12FF, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            skill  = br.ReadInt32();
        }


        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("Player.chr")))
        {
            bw.Seek(0x12FF, SeekOrigin.Begin); // go to position
            bw.Write(skill + 10); // plus 10 skill points
        }
```

It's code replace old value "skill" in file.

Comment: Thank you! Спасибо!
А если offset не постоянный, можно как-то найти по строке идущей перед этим значением? На скрине в вопросе это строка skillPoints

Comment: Мне подсказывали, что вроде как можно:
"Считываете строку из файла, когда встречаете "skillPoints" просто читаете 2 или 4 байта данных о скилле, запоминаете оффсет для дальнейшего редактирования. Всё." 
Но я не понял как это реализовать

Comment: Надо смотреть сам файл. Возможно там есть текстовые поля и тогда, да можно попробовать найти их, а потом вычислить offset. Т.е. я бы делал так, сначала все вычитал как текст, нашел позицию: string content = File.ReadAllText("Player.chr"); var offset = contet.IndexOf("skillPoints"); if(offset>0) offset +="skillPoints".Length;
А дальше можно уже использовать код из ответа, заменив 0x12FF на offset

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("Player.chr");
data[0x12FF] += 10;
File.WriteAllBytes("Player.chr", data);
```

There's a caveat: This is manipulating a byte (8-bit).  If your target is something like an int (16/32-bit), you'll have to adjust accordingly.